# sbt intellij twirl templates

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-14, twirl

I am not sure how to get twirl templates to work with Intellij IDEA 14

My build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "twirl-api_2.11" % "1.1.1"
```

My text template:

```
@(date: java.util.Date)
hello world
```

My call to render:

```
  println(play.twirl.api.Txt.testTemplate.render(new Date()))
```

The compiler error:

```
Error:(26, 34) value testTemplate is not a member of object play.twirl.api.Txt
  println(play.twirl.api.Txt.testTemplate.render(new Date()))
                             ^
```

I read somewhere that I should compile the template outside Intellij by using:

```
sbt compile
```

I am not sure if this will work.  Also, I have the plugin for sbt installed, but I don't know how to get a command line version set up on the mac.

Any advice for me?

Comment: In intellij please add to from target generated sources (target/scala-2.11/someDirs)

Comment: Doing this to the twirl folder in target did not fix the issue for me and creates a duplicate class problem that takes a lot of fiddling around to fix.

Comment: I got it working with Intellij 2017.